# Angular HttpPost to Oauth2 return 401

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, oauth-2.0

I want use oauth2 in my ionic app but i get error:

> Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 401 ()
>
> Error: Http failure response for http://localhost:8080/oauth/token: 401 OK

Response:

> {"timestamp":1502983544253,"status":401,"error":"Unauthorized","message":"Full authentication is required to access this resource","path":"/oauth/token"}

Angular function:

```
login(username, password) : Observable<any> {

 let params: HttpParams = new HttpParams();
 params.set('username', username);
 params.set('password', password);
 params.set('client_id', this.clientId);
 params.set('client_secret', this.clientSecret);
 params.set('grant_type', 'password');


 let headers = new HttpHeaders();
 headers.set('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');

 return this.http.post(this.EndPointUrl, {
   params:params
 }, { headers:headers}).map(this.handleData).
   catch(this.handleError);  }
```

All params are correct.

```
curl -X POST --user 'U:P' -d 'grant_type=password&username=USER&password=PASS' localhost:8080/oauth/toke
```

return

```
{"access_token":"d88c1c5e-d2c0-4c96-9e69-a62816d0a5e8","token_type":"bearer","refresh_token":"8f82f0b0-38a3-4c05-9590-43d3ec2f36b9","expires_in":3599,"scope":"read write"}
```

I can get token using PostMan and curl, [CORS](https://i.stack.imgur.com/scmnI.png) in my server is enabled for this endpoint so i think the auth server works properly.

Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Is it not your options request that is failing?

Comment: I dont think so,  look https://i.stack.imgur.com/scmnI.png .
I think that angular doesn't send data in post. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45751648/angular4-doesnt-send-post-data

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was in dependency. Most likely HTTPClient((@angular/common/http) from angular 4.3.4 desn't work with ionic for this moment. With Http (@angular/http) from angular 4.1.3 above code works properly.

Answer (score 0):

Try to add this 
`headers.set('Authentication', 'Basic client_id:client_secret');` (in Base 64)

Comment: How about your angular request ?

Comment: maybe you can change to headers.set('Content-Type', 'application/json');

Comment: Scope is correct too, if i set incorrect scope then i get error "invalid_scope".

Comment: When i change Content-type to aplication/json i get the same error.

Comment: I added headers.set('Authentication','Basi c'+btoa(this.clientId+":"+this.clientSecret));" But the error is still.